# wp_query returns match with no criteria

Tags: wp-query

I have a small search form that should redirect to a page based on the "Idea Number".  Idea Number is a unique number, so there should only be one match at any time.  My query fails with no criteria though.  The code below will..

1. Redirects perfectly if there is a match for idea_num
2. Redirects back to the originating page with an error if no match
3. **If no criteria... it still will redirect to a page where the idea_num doesn't match???  What am I missing here?**

---

```
$post_types = array("cool_ideas", "bad_ideas");

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => 1,
    'post_type'     => $post_types,
    'meta_key'      => 'idea_num',
    'meta_value'    => $idea_num,
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_query->have_posts()){
    $the_query->the_post();
    wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink(get_the_ID()));
    exit();
}else{
    wp_safe_redirect(get_permalink($ref_pid) . '?idea=' . $idea_num);
    exit();
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Do you make sure $idea_num contains an integer before trying to use it?

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the issue.  When empty, it would still return a value.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into this for a big, what I discovered by reviewing the actual SQL via $the_query->request was that if no meta value identified it will return true simply because the query eliminates it.

The solution was to simply include the the meta as an array and use the "compare" operator.